# Storing Reference to Non-Static Method

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm trying to create a collection of values that each correspond to an action. This way, I'll be able to search the collection for a particular value and then call the associated action in a generic way.

So, here was my first stab at it:

```
public class CommandInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Action<RunArgument> Action { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<CommandInfo> Commands = new List<CommandInfo>
    {
        new CommandInfo { Name = "abc", Action = AbcAction } // <== ERROR HERE
    };

    public void AbcAction(RunArgument arg)
    {
        ; // Do something useful here
    }
}
```

In this case, the declaration of the new `CommandInfo` inside the `Commands` collection gives me the error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MyNameSpace.MyClass.AbcAction(MyNameSpace.RunArgument)'

Surely there must be a way to store a reference to a non-static method like this. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Surely there must be a way to store a reference to a non-static method like this. Can someone help me out?

There is, just not within a field initializer. So this works fine:

```
public List<CommandInfo> Commands = new List<CommandInfo>();

public MyClass()
{
    Commands.Add(new CommandInfo { Name = "abc",
                                   Action = AbcAction });
}
```

... or perform the whole assignment within the constructor. Note that this doesn't really have anything to do with delegates - it's incidental, on the basis that you're effectively referring to `this.AbcAction`. In every other way, it's equivalent to this problem:

```
public class Foo
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = this.x; // This has the same problem...
}
```

(I hope you don't *really* have a public field, of course...)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand why my syntax is not accepted but yours is. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @JonathanWood: Yes - you're trying to construct it *in a field initializer*, and you can't refer to `this` within a field initializer. See if my edit helps.

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't that you can't store a reference to a non-static member, it is that you cannot reference a non-static member in a field initializer.  Field initializers can only reference static or constant values.  Move the initialization of `Commands` to the constructor and it will work.

```
public class CommandInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Action<RunArgument> Action { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<CommandInfo> Commands;

    public MyClass 
    {
        Commands = new List<CommandInfo>
        {
            new CommandInfo { Name = "abc", Action = AbcAction }
        };
    }

    public void AbcAction(RunArgument arg)
    {
        ; // Do something useful here
    }
}
```